# Regex in notepad++ to mark multi-line pattern and delete all unmarked lines, and keep all marked lines including the ones marked after the first line

Tags: regex, notepad++, bookmarks

I have xml tags that start on one line and end in another. Regex properly marks the lines when I use `<tag>(.*?)<tag/>`, but when I tell notepad++ to remove unbookmarked lines, it only keeps the first line of every single multi-line mark.

Is this a bug? Is there a setting I have to tinker with?

To clarify, I have 1 marked element and it spans multiple lines. Even though all lines are marked, only the first is bookmarked, so clear all unbookmarked clears the marked lines after the first bookmarked line. How can I get all lines in the element bookmarked, or keep them when I clear all bookmarked?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60795392/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: I already find everything I want marked, is marked. The problem is only the first line of every result has a blue bullet next to it, so when I tell it to clear all unbookmarked lines, it clears the marked lines that occured after a newline (which do not get bullet points for some reason).

Comment: Everything works fine for me with **my** test case, please, give yours.

Comment: Are you even reading what I wrote? I have 1 marked element and it spans multiple lines. Even though all lines are marked, only the first is bookmarked, so clear all unbookmarked clears the marked lines after the first bookmarked line.

Comment: What version(s) of Notepad++ are being used. Do not say "latest", be explicit.

Comment: Version 7.5.6 64-bit

Comment: Updated to 7.8.5 and have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way around this issue is to make the xml tags one line or find another way to process xml (which I have not found).